# Random Int IllegualArgumentException

Tags: android

I am using this code to using a Random generator to generate random positions.

But i keep getting this error

```
11-06 21:33:07.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12796): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
11-06 21:33:07.364: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12796):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:186)
```

Here is the code i am using.

```
private void addFace() {
     Random rand = new Random();

        float x = (int) roof.getHeight() + mBallTextureRegion.getWidth();
        float minY = mBallTextureRegion.getHeight();
        float maxY = (int)(roof.getHeight() - mBallTextureRegion.getHeight());
        float rangeY = maxY - minY;
                     //The error points here
        float y = rand.nextInt((int)rangeY) + minY;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That means that rangeY is negative. Check the logic that you're using to assign that value.